# Covariance between two posterior predictive distributions?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, predictive-models, posterior

Suppose we have three features $x_i \sim N(0, 1)$ for $i=1,2,3$. We then use Bayesian linear regression with interpolant $f(x, w) = wX$, such that we model y as $N(f(x, w), \beta)$, i.e., with a Gaussian likelihood. Then we set a zero mean isotropic gaussian prior on the parameters $w$ such that this prior is infinitely broad. We know that the posterior distribution in this case will be gaussian and so will the predictive distribution.

My question is, if we consider two models, one with x1 and x2, and another with x1, x2 and x3, and we generate the predictive distribution for a single test point for each, can we say anything about the covariance between these two predictive distribitions? What if x1, x2 and x3 are known to be indepednant?

Comment: Covariance is defined between two random variables (with a joint probability distribution), not between two distributions

Comment: Yes but can we say anything about the joint distribution then? @J.Delaney

Comment: i.e., can we say anything about the joint predictive distribution

Comment: Joint distribution of what ? you can independently sample  $P(y|x_1,x_2)$ and $P(y|x_1,x_2,x_3)$, but the covariance of these sample will be trivially zero as they are independent

Comment: But they arent independant, since if for example x3 has no informative information in the regression problem, i.e., w3=0., then these distributions will be perfectly correlated, right? @J.Delaney

Comment: Again, there is no notion of correlation between two *distributions*.  You can generate independent samples from exactly the same distribution (that's what $i.i.d$ means)